# EditorConfig not being used by files in nested directories in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation, editorconfig

I have set up a `.editorconfig` file in the `root` of my project like this:

```
root = true

[*]
indent-style = space
indent-size = 2
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

In order to fix this,I tried adding:

```
[**/**/*.js]
indent-style = space
indent-size = 2
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

This is respected by all files in the root directory but not by files within nested directories.[image]

Comment: Your original setup should work. It sounds like a bug. Can you make a bug report?